# What space classifies bundles of K(pi,1)'s?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given a discrete group $G$ (**not** assumed to be abelian), is there a nice construction of a topological space which classifies bundles of $K(G,1)$'s?  I guess I should take something like $B\operatorname{Aut}(K(\pi,1))$ where $\operatorname{Aut}(K(\pi,1))$ is the monoid of self homotopy equivalences of some fixed $K(\pi,1)$.  I don't know if this makes any sense, though.

Morally speaking, things are defined as follows.  A bundle of $K(\pi,1)$'s over a space $X$ is a fibration $Y\to X$ whose fibers are $K(\pi,1)$'s.  Two bundles of $K(\pi,1)$'s $Y_1,Y_2\to X$ are said to be isomorphic iff there is a map $Y_1\to Y_2$ of spaces over $X$ which is a homotopy equivalence on each fiber.

Comment: How about $K(Out(G),1)$? The (almost) example where this is frequently used is when $G$ is the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic surface $S_g$, so one uses the moduli space $M_g$ of $S_g$ (regarded as an orbifold) for classification of bundles with surface fiber. Then the orbifold $M_g$ is essentially $K(Map_g, 1)$, where $Map_g$ is the mapping class group of $S_g$, i.e., $Map_g=Out(G)$. 

Comment: Yes, it's just as you think. You can apply the usual bar construction to make a simplicial space from that topological monoid, and get the space you want from that. By the way, $\pi_1$ of this space, which is $\pi_0$ of the monoid, is the group of outer automorphisms of $G$, cokernel of the map $G\to Aut(G)$ that takes $g$ to $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$. And $\pi_2$ of the space, which is $\pi_1$ of the monoid, is the center of $G$, the kernel of the same map $G\to Aut(G)$. And the rest of the homotopy groups are trivial.

Comment: A lemma I find helpful: if you preserve basepoints, $Aut(B\pi,\*)=Aut(\pi)$ for general groups; $BAut(\pi)$ classifies bundles−with−section. The fiber sequence $Aut(B\pi,\*)\to Aut(B\pi)\to B\pi$ shows that $\pi_0(Aut(B\pi))=Out(\pi)$ and $\pi_1(Aut(B\pi))=Z(\pi)$.

Comment: @Tom: How is that related to the classifying space of the $2$-group associated to the crossed module $G \to Aut(G)$?

Comment: I just want to add that the article "Moore-Postnikov towers for fibrations in which $\pi_1$(fiber) is non-abelian" by Richard Hill (available at http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1102867869) goes into great detail regarding the information in Tom's comment above. It describes the homotopy type of the classifying fibration $BG\to B\textrm{Aut}_*(BG)\to B\textrm{Aut}(BG)$ very thoroughly.

Comment: @Ulrich: The first example on the nlab page on crossed modules (ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed%2Bmodule) might indicate they coincide, at least to someone more knowledgeable of crossed modules than me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any space $F$ you can form the topological monoid $Aut(F)$ and take its classifying space. That will classify Hurewicz fibrations with fiber $F$. A little care is needed since $Aut(F)$ won't generally have the homotopy type of a CW complex unless $F$ is a finite CW complex, which $K(G,1)$ is usually not. For the proof it is sensible to take base spaces of the homotopy types of CW complexes.  One source for a complete proof is "Classifying spaces and fibrations", #15 on my web page.  (There are two obvious notions of the right equivalence relation on fibrations, but these give the same answer, as shown in "Fiberwise localization and completion'', #31 on my web page.)

Answer (score 1):

To put another context to the above comments and answers, recall that a *crossed module* consists of a morphism $\mu: M \to P$  together with an action of $P$ on the right of the group $M$ satisfying the two axioms

1. $\mu(m^p)= p^{-1}\mu(m) p$;
2. $ m^{-1} nm = m^{\mu n}$,

for all $m,n \in M, p \in P$. This definition is due to J.H.C. Whitehead in 1946.

Examples of crossed modules are:

1. the inner automorphism crossed module $\chi: M \to Aut(M)$ for any group $M$;
2. the inclusion $M \to P$ of a normal subgroup $M$ of $P$;
3. the zero map $0: M \to P$ for any right $P$-module $M$;
4. the induced map $\pi_1(F) \to \pi_1(E)$ for any pointed fibration $F \to E \to B$;

and others!

Any such crossed module has a *classifying space* $B(M \to P)$ whose homotopy groups are trivial above dimension $2$, and with $\pi_1 \cong Coker \mu$, $\pi_2 \cong Ker \mu$. More details of these facts are in the book [EMS Tract 15](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html). Crossed modules are equivalent to group objects in the category of groupoids, and this gives one way of defining the classifying space, using bisimplicial sets, and are conveniently regarded as *$2$-dimensional versions of groups*, since they model pointed weak homotopy $2$-types. Note that the second homotopy group, even considered as a module over $\pi_1$, is generally  but a pale shadow of the homotopy $2$-type.

There is also a Seifert-van Kampen type theorem with values in crossed modules, and this allows some computations of nonabelian second relative homotopy groups. See again the [EMS Tract 15](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html).

Comment: Hello! I'm reading your book Nonabelian algebraic topology and encountered the notion of a crossed module over a groupoid in section 6.2, where the first condition is that 
$$\mu(x^a)=\mu(x)^a$$ However, the action of $a$ is on elements in $M$. Am I right in assuming that this is just
$$\mu(x^a)=-a+\mu(x)+a$$ similar to the case of groups ?